# How to query only a particular part of the string on BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table that has column called topics under which I have result like this
 `/finance/investing/funds/mutual funds`. How do I write a query on BigQuery to yield me only the word between the first two slashes i.e. in this example I would like it to return only finance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just developing Gordons answer further to work with your `ARRAY<STRING>`. All you need to do, is just `UNNEST` the array before passing it to the `SPLIT` function mentioned before.

Simple sample:

```
SELECT SPLIT(string, '/')[safe_ordinal(2)]
FROM UNNEST([ '/finance/investing/funds/mutual funds', '/random/investing/funds/mutual 
funds' ]) AS string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`split()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split):

```
select split('/finance/investing/funds/mutual funds', '/')[safe_ordinal(2)]
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it looks like I forgot to mention that the column is String data type and Repeated mode where I get the following error `No matching signature for function SPLIT for argument types: ARRAY<STRING>, STRING. Supported signatures: SPLIT(STRING, [STRING]); SPLIT(BYTES, BYTES) at [1:8]` when I use the query `select split(topics, '/')[safe_ordinal(2)] FROM 'bigquery-project.dataset.table'`

Comment: "A result like this" is a *string*.  This answers the question that you have asked.  If you cannot adapt this answer, then ask a new question.